# ¿Como insertar datos en un input y devolverlos en un div?

Tags: jquery

Hola como puedo insertar texto en un input y al dar enter este texto que se muestre en un div, pero si inserto otro texto que no se borre el antiguo, solo si lo borro yo.

lo que quiero hacer exactamente es como el campo etiqueta de esta pagina, pero en vez de guardarlo en el input guardarlo en un div y poder borar, adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con este codigo me escribe todo antes de presionar enter.

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Incluye texto con jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#campo').on('keyup', function(){
            var valor = $('#campo').val();
            $('#reflejar').text(valor);
            //$('#campo').val("Hola mundo");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="campo">
<div id="reflejar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitarás crear los `HTMLElement` de forma dinámica.
Te incluyo un ejemplo sin usar `JQuery`. Tú puedes hacer la traducción, si quieres.

```js
const inputs = [];

const field = document.querySelector(`#field`);
const container = document.querySelector(`#container`);

field.addEventListener(`keypress`, event => {
    if (enterPressed(event)) {
        addElement();

        // In case you want to clear the input field.
        field.value = ``;
    }
});

const enterPressed = event => event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13;

const addElement = () => {
    const text = field.value;
    const element = createElement(text);
    addRemoveButton(element);

    container.appendChild(element);

    // In case you want to store all inputs
    inputs.push(text);
}

const createElement = text => {
    const el = document.createElement(`div`);
    el.innerHTML = text;
    el.classList.add(`element`);
    
    return el;
}

const removeElement = element => container.removeChild(element);
const addRemoveButton = element => {
    const btn = document.createElement(`button`);
    btn.classList.add(`remove-button`);
    btn.addEventListener(`click`, () => removeElement(element));
    btn.innerHTML = `x`;

    element.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
#field {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.element {
    border: 1px solid rgb(22, 197, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightblue;

    color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;

    margin-left: 10px;
}

.element:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.element .remove-button {
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(22, 197, 255);
    border: none;

    font-size: 1.3em;
    
    transform: scaleY(0.8) 
                        translateX(30%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="field">
    <div id="container" class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Vamos por partes.
Para cada evento `keypress` en el `input`, miro si la tecla pulsada es el `enter`, que tiene por código el número `13` (función `enterPressed`). En ese caso, añadiré un `HTMLElement` nuevo al contenedor.
No modifico directamente el texto dentro del contenedor. Mantener elementos separados ayuda a tener un control más concreto sobre cada uno de ellos, así como los estilos.
La función `addElement` crea un `div`, le pone como `innerHTML` el texto del `input` y lo añade al contenedor.

Adicionalmente, también creo un botón de forma dinámica y me suscribo al `click` para poder borrar el elemento.

Opcionalmente, se añaden las clases de estilos a los elementos creados y guardo en un array en memoria todos los inputs del usuario.
Realmente, con ese array no se hace nada, ahora mismo. Des del mismo array se podría borrar también los elementos. Se me ocurre de guardar un objecto con el elemento, por ejemplo

```
const inputs = [];

//...
const addElement = () => {
    // ...
    inputs.push({
        text,
        element
    });
}
```

De este modo lo podemos rescatar tanto por índixe como por el texto para luego borrarlo tanto del `container` como del array.

Espero que haya ayudado. 
Cualquier duda me comentas.

Comment: si eso queria muchas gracias